# Android SQLite, как очистить таблицу

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sdk

Добрый день.

Подскажите как в Android SQLite удалить все записи из таблицы?

Comment: delete from ИМЯ_ТАБЛИЦЫ?

Comment: myDatabase.delete(TABLE,null, null);  Почитать [о работе с SQLLite](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/sqlite/android-sqlite.php) в Android

Comment: Спасибо. Правильный ответ db.execSQL("DELETE FROM" + " table_name");

Comment: Это один из вариантов через "сырой" запрос. Класс `SQLiteOpenHelper` [имеет собственные методы вставки, обновления, удаления и выборки из БД SQLite](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/sqlite/android-sqlite.php), которые несколько безопаснее и лаконичнее "сырых" запросов.

Answer (score 3):

Можно попробовать так :

```
db.delete("TABLE_NAME", null, null);
```

будьте внимательнее с ковычками .

Ну или же так :

```
/**
 * Remove all users and groups from database.
 */
public void removeAll()
{
    // db.delete(String tableName, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs);
    // If whereClause is null, it will delete all rows.
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase(); // helper is object extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    db.delete(DatabaseHelper.TAB_USERS, null, null);
    db.delete(DatabaseHelper.TAB_USERS_GROUP, null, null);
}
```

Comment: чем отличается первый и второй вариант, кроме указания разных имен таблиц?

Comment: по сути ничем, первый это способ второй это явный пример